# How to create unique combinations out of provided keys-values?

Tags: algorithm

Let's say I have a struct Product **with unknown and variable amount of attributes-values.** The attributes-values come from a user **at runtime.** One product with a inuque combination of attributes and values form a *product_variant*.

For intance, user may create 4 attributes:

- size (5 values)
- material (3 values)
- design (2 values)
- colour (9 values)

and thus there'll be 5 * 3 * 2 * 9 = 270 unique product variants. But the amount of attributes may be any and isn't known at compile time.

Example:

*product_variant* with:

```
%{ 
  size => m,
  material => paper,
  design => ds_abc,
  colour => red,
}
```

How do I traverse all the attributes with their respective values and thus create 270 unique product variants? What'll be an algorithm?

Not with a library function.

In C, Python or pseudo code.

Comment: Are you familiar with Backtracking?

Answer (score 0):

If you have to create all unique products, I sugest use loops:
Example in Python:

```
    sizes = {}
    materials= {}
    designs = {}
    colours= {}
    
    products = {}
    
    for size in sizes:                 //for any size
        for meterial in material:      //for any material
            for design in designs:     //for any design
                for colour in colours: //for any colour
                    products.add(make_product(size, material, design, colour)) // create product object and add to collection
```

For sure collection is unique - use collection type `set`

Comment: No. I've already mentioned it in my question and tell you again - the attributes and their values AREN'T KNOWN at compile time. They get created only AT RUNTIME! Your solution won't work because it assumes that there're only 4 attributes. But there can 2, 8, 5, 33 or any other number of them whatsoever.